# My Desktop PC monitor thru DisplayPort 1.4 sometimes doesn't light up

Tags: boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

Sometimes when I boot up my PC (cold boot) the monitor shows a stable black screen instead of the BIOS password menu and nothing happens. Any clue why this might happen?
Since no OS is booted at that moment OS is irrelevant, I tried not having anything live on the HDMI port, it seems to have no effect.

Any clue how to fix this or debug this further? It's a minor nuisance, but still pretty annoying. The only way to reach the password menu is to turn the PC off and on.

The graphics card is a RTX 3080 if that matters.

Comment: May be your computer can not correctly detect which port is the correct one to output the image to? if your CPU also has a graphics core there are even more possibilities to select the wrong output port. Trying an alternative cable and different port on the graphic card may have an impact, even if the BIOS image is pretty low resolution and frequency and thus does not require a high bandwidth. Does your monitor show an OSD if there is no input?

Comment: @Robert My CPU does not have an iGPU. Monitor does light up with DisplayPort 1.